Import NumPy private C-API
I’m working on a C++ project, in which I use the NumPy C-API. Only part of this API is public. I would like to import a function belonging to NumPy's private / internal API. How can I achieve that?
The standard way of importing the NumPy C-API in a project involves including its header files from
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy.
There’s no shared library object that I need to link my executable to.
Hence, I would imagine it necessary to modify NumPy’s source code, build from source and then install using pip. Then the newly exposed header file would appear inside
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy. (Conversely, including the header files directly from the numpy source repo, i.e. not from the installed python numpy package, throws an error that tells me not to include directly from source repo.)
So I have a high-level idea but I’m not sure about the implementation details of this plan.
Assume I want to import the function
NPY_NO_EXPORT PyObject *
array_richcompare(PyArrayObject *self, PyObject *other, int cmp_op)

from
/path-to-numpy-repo/numpy/_core/src/multiarray/arrayobject.h
What would be the steps necessary to expose / import just array_richcompare?
What would be the steps necessary to expose / import all functions defined in arrayobject.h?
What would be the steps necessary to expose / import all header files in the NumPy repo?
Thanks
What I've tried so far
I removed all NPY_NO_EXPORT modifiers from the repo. Also, I removed all instances of the following clause
#ifndef _MULTIARRAYMODULE
#error You should not include this
#endif

, e.g. from the following file
/path-to-numpy-repo/numpy/_core/src/multiarray/arrayobject.h.
Then I built NumPy using the official instructions, i.e. I ran
pip install ..
The newly generated numpy python package include directory still contained the same header files as before (no new ones).
When I then ran my C++ executable, there was some error. I can't recall precisely what it was but most likely it was a compiler error complaining that the array_richcompare symbol from the private API is undefined.
